# Limits and domains

Tags: calculus

According to my book

> Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be two real valued functions with the same domain such that $f(x)< g(x)$ for all values of $x$. Then for any real number a limit of $f(x)$ is less than the limit of $g(x)$.

Why do they need to have the same domain?

Comment: Or else how can you say "$f(x)<g(x)$ for all $x$"? e.g. do we have $\sqrt{-1}<(-1)^2$?

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

The same domain is an assumption for the statement in order to consider consistent limit for both the functions.

Note that the statement is not true in general, let consider for example

$$g(x)= \frac{\sin x}x\quad f(x)=\cos x \frac{\sin x}x$$

for $x\in \left(0,\frac \pi 2\right)$ with $f(x)<g(x)$ then

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x)=\lim_{x \to 0^+} g(x)=1$$

or also

$$g(x)=1\quad f(x)=\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}$$

with $f(x)<g(x)$ but

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=1$$

The correct statement when both limits at $x=x_0$ exist is

$$f(x)<g(x) \implies \lim_{x \to x_0} f(x)\le \lim_{x \to x_0} g(x)$$

---

As noticed by [Benjamin](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/810273/benjamin) in the comments, dropping the assumptions that both limits exist, we can generalize the statement as follows

$$\limsup_{x\to x_0}f(x)\le \liminf_{x\to x_0}g(x)$$

Comment: Just to add some more infos: If you drop the assumptions, that both limits exist, you can generalize to $$ \limsup_{x\to x_0}f(x)\le \liminf_{x\to x_0}g(x). $$

Comment: @Benjamin Yes thanks! I add also this observation.